# How to create an event handler for multiple buttons using a for loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I want to set 50 button's click event to - private void buttonOnOff(object sender, EventArgs e).

It works when I write my code like this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button1.Click += button_Click;
        button2.Click += button_Click;
        button3.Click += button_Click;
       .......
    }
```

But is it possible do do this using a for loop. When I try I get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error is on this line of code: Controls[buttonName].Click += buttonOnOff;

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string buttonName;

        for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)    // Does a check for each button.
        {
            buttonName = "button" + i;
            Controls[buttonName].Click += buttonOnOff;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are doing it in the ctor why not just add them via the designer?  Actually, if you are getting an NRE, it s a different issue (and a dupe)

Comment: Do you want to add the same handler to every button on the form (`foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>()) {...}`), or only to some subset of the buttons?

Comment: Just 50 buttons I want to add, not all buttons. I've created the buttons in the designer. Now I just want it so that when you click on any of them it runs this method.

Comment: Just replace `i < 51` with `i <= Controls.OfType<Button>().Count();`

Comment: Just keep getting this error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Have you tried debugging the loop? On which instance exactly it fails? The first one? Last One? Inbetween?

Comment: In the loop you are getting the button controls by name from the controls list. Your exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" simply means that there is no object with this name in the list.

So either there is a button missing or named else in your 1-50 set.

Comment: @casiosmu  You should not post answers to the question as a comment.  If you want to suggest an answer to the question you should do so by posting an answer.

Comment: @Servy now I'm a bit confused ;-) one says this the other that. But for now I think I'll let it as comment, because it doesnt answer the main question. Thank you anyway for backing me up.

Comment: @casiosmu It answers the question asked (unlike the currently provided answer).  I'm aware that someone erroneously said that it wasn't an answer, even though it is an answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my loop. Even if I just go around the loop for 3 buttons it doesn't work. I definitely have 3 buttons - button1, button2, button3. If I change there click event like this - button1.Click += button_Click; I get no errors. But once I mention Controls, as in - Controls[buttonName].Click += buttonOnOff; It reads the button as null! Why is this?

Comment: Something wrong gone with  your design - if you have 50 buttons with same event handler on the form - you can consider using `DataGridView` or re-think your UI design

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the forms controls (and even specifically buttons using Linq) - something like this:

```
foreach (Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    // here, you could check the name, if necessary
    // and add your handler
    b.Click += buttonOnOff;
}
```

**Elevating some good comments to add to the answer:**

As @mars-red and @donboitnott point out, don't allow this code to execute more than once.  In your current example, you are doing it in the Form's constructor, so that is good.

Also, @mars-red mentions the Tag property of your buttons.  If you had other buttons on your form and didn't want to try to figure out which buttons, you could add a specific value to the Tag of each and just check that - so, something like this:

```
foreach (Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if (b.Tag.ToString() == "SomeIndicator")
    {
        b.Click += buttonOnOff;
    }
}
```

And, of course, you could also just look for a particular pattern in the names of the buttons.

Your "object reference" issue doesn't make sense if you are using this code.  The iterator is giving you specific instances of buttons, so "b" should always be a button in the loop.

**Final Update:**

The main issue was that the Form wasn't the "container" of the button controls (they were in a panel).  So, instead of using the Form's controls, the user should have been using the Panel's controls (something like this):

```
SomePanel.Controls[buttonName].Click += buttonOnOff;
```

Comment: Just keep getting this error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I like this answer.  You could even use the "Tag" property of the controls that need to be targeted for wiring up to this one event handler.  Also don't forget to remove event handlers if/when appropriate. Robri1989, make sure you're iterating over a collection that actually contains your targeted controls, and make sure it is the same "Button" type as your targeted controls.

Comment: To expand upon what @mars-red said:  don't allow this code to execute more than once without first removing the previously assigned handlers.  If you fail, every click will produce >1 calls to the handler.  Moreover, you can wind up with memory problems if those handlers are not properly removed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my loop. Even if I just go around the loop for 3 buttons it doesn't work. I definitely have 3 buttons - button1, button2, button3. If I change there click event like this - button1.Click += button_Click; I get no errors. But once I mention Controls, as in - Controls[buttonName].Click += buttonOnOff; It reads the button as null! Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure that the Form is the Parent of the Buttons?  If they are in some sort of container control, they won't be in the Form's Controls collection.  So, let's say they were in a GroupBox, you would need to do SomeGroupBoxName.Controls[buttonName] ...

Answer (score 0):

At first declare a control array variable and add your buttons to it.

```
Control[] B_list = new Control[] { Button1, Button2, Button3, ...... }
```

Then in the for loop, use these serially like

```
Button btn;
for(int index = 0; index < 50; index++)
{
   btn = (Button)B_list[index];
   btn.Click += new EventHandler(buttonOnOff);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*OK, undeleting this in request of @Servy:*

In the loop you are getting the button controls by name from the controls list. Your exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" simply means that there is no object with this name in the list.

So either there is a button missing or named else in your 1-50 set.

If you are using @snow_FFFFFF's solution and the error persists that is really strange.

Nevertheless, as I already suggested: debug the loop! Check on which button name/instance it crashes, check the contents of `Controls` (you have to go a bit down the private members) etc

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.  It's a response to a comment.  You should delete this and move the thought to the appropriate place.

Comment: @DonBoitnott How is it not answering the question?  In what way is it a comment?

Comment: @DonBoitnott I agree he asked how to do it in a loop, but he also asked why he is getting the error

Comment: I suppose it _sort of_ answers it, but only in providing a definition for what the exception is.  The question seems more like "how do I fix it", and this does not attempt a solution.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my loop. Even if I just go around the loop for 3 buttons it doesn't work. I definitely have 3 buttons - button1, button2, button3. If I change there click event like this - button1.Click += button_Click; I get no errors. But once I mention Controls, as in - Controls[buttonName].Click += buttonOnOff; It reads the button as null! Why is this?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `Controls` in debugger? Does it work if you run the loop outside ctor?